# Login to AppStore over cellular data, jump on public wifi, download/install app is "safe"?

Tags: iphone, wifi, security, cellular-data, tcp

Is it "safe" to install an App as such:
(1) using only a cellular data connection (wifi turned off) login to the App Store.
(2) enable wifi.
(3) connect to public wifi network.
(4) disable cellular data.
(5) download app.
(6) enable cellular data.
(7) disable wifi.
(8) install app.

The iPhone can jump between wifi and cellular data without breaking a tcp connection right?

Comment: It seems if a network can MITM the app download - you don't gain any security by signing in and exchanging keys / tokens off that network. I'm not sure how you see TCP - but perhaps you're asking if multipathing would not invalidate a cached credential since TCP connections surely break when you switch a network interface. Basically, I'm not sure how to even edit this to get it down to something I could start to answer.

Comment: TLS should make it safe even without your steps.

Answer (score 2):

Your scenario won't work I'm afraid, because a TCP connection is created between a source IP address and port, and a destination address and port.

In your scenario, your phone's source IP address would change when switching network interfaces. This would break the connection, so the App store will not recognize that you already connected before, even though you securely connected over TLS (HTTPS)